# Dynamic color setting button

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

How to dynamically created button to set the blue color as in the Windows game Sapper? This is a part of code

```
    self.buttons = []
    for i in xrange(self.HeightOfField):
        l=[]
        for j in xrange(self.WidthOfField):
            b=QtGui.QPushButton()
            b.setFixedSize(40,30)
            l.append(b)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(b, i, j)
            self.gridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(j, 40)
        self.buttons.append(l)
        self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(i, 26)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the easiest way to set the colour of a button would be to use a [stylesheet](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-syntax.html) using [`.setStyleSheet`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#setStyleSheet).

```
b.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;')
```

You can use RGB colours, but it's easier to use HTML keyword names. Take a look at [this table](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords) from W3C.